# Assign many lines to one name

Tags: r

Say within my r code I have:

```
a<-some code
b<-some code
c<-some code
```

and I would like to have this block of code somehow saved so that I can call it up when I like. How can I save the whole block as `blockOfCode` so that I call just call it up as a macro? In other words the following:

```
Z<-some code
a<-some code
b<-some code
c<-some code
Y<-some code
a<-some code
b<-some code
c<-some code
Z<-some code
```

can be rewritten as:

```
Z<-some code
blockOfCode
Y<-some code
blockOfCode
Z<-some code
```

Comment: are you asking how to write a function in R? (add return(a) at the end or read some tutorials) - Happy NY ;)

Comment: @BigDataScientist I did try that, but sometimes my block of code contains many things happening and I don't want just to return one output. I'm looking for something that saves the block of code as a name and I can call it again when I want.

Comment: Its still not clear what you are asking, at least to me? Try producing a small example of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is called a *macro* (as contrasted with a *function*, which takes arguments and returns values rather than modifying variables in the current environment). R doesn't really have macros. [This 2001 R News article by Thomas Lumley](https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2001-3.pdf) begins:

> A familiar source of questions on the R mailing lists
>   is the newly converted R user who is trying to write
>   SAS or Stata code in R. Bill Venables then points out
>   to them that R is not a macro language, and gently
>   explains that there is a much easier solution to their
>   problems. In this article I will explain what a macro
>   is, why it’s good that R isn’t a macro language, and
>   how to make it into one.

The code provided by Lumley was put into the `gtools::defmacro()` function, described a bit more [here](https://matloff.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/macros-in-r/). Here's an example:

```
library(gtools)
## defmacro() needs an argument, even if you don't use it
f <- defmacro(x,expr = {a <- a+1})
a <- 0
f()  ## you do need the parentheses here
a <- a+1
```

The value of `a` is now 1.

`expr` can contain as much code as you want, so you can execute multiple expressions.

But please do read Lumley's article.

Answer (score 0):

Your `blockOfCode` can be handled in a few ways, but generally it will require you to learn about environments.

If you do everything in the global environment, the following will work.

```
a <- b <- c <- NA

blockOfCode <- function() {
  a <<- 1
  b <<- 2
  c <<- 3
}

Z <- 11
blockOfCode()
Y <- 22
blockOfCode()
Z <- 33
```

The deep assignment arrow `<<-` will assign to the global environment if there isn't a variable in the local environment (the function environment). The first line `a <- b <- c <- NA` is necessary because if you use deep assignment without first creating the variable `c` it will give an error, probably because `c()` is used to create vectors. Generally I try to avoid using `c` as a variable for this reason.

In addition, the deep assignment is generally discouraged because it can cause some unpredictable results.

You can instead use `assign` and specify the environment. In this case using `parent.frame` will move you up from the function environment to the global environment.

```
blockOfCode <- function() {
  assign("a", 1, envir = parent.frame())
  assign("b", 2, envir = parent.frame())
  assign("c", 3, envir = parent.frame())
}

Z <- 11
blockOfCode()
Y <- 22
blockOfCode()
Z <- 33
```

This has the benefit on not needing to create the a, b, and c variables ahead of time. You could also specify another environment rather than the global.

All that being said, your example might be too simple to illustrate what you're trying to do. There is no reason to run your `blockOfCode` more than once, since the values of a, b, and c will not having changed. In your more complicated real world situation, the above might need to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possibilities:

**1) eval/substitute** Put the block of code in an R function but when writing the function put `eval.parent(substitute({` at the beginning and `}))` at the end and then just run the function at the appropriate points.  No packages are used.

```
block <- function() eval.parent(substitute({
  a <- 1
  b <- 2
  c <- 3
}))

Z <- 1
block()
cat("Z:", Z, "a:", a, "b:", b, "c:", c, "\n")
## Z: 1 a: 1 b: 2 c: 3 
rm(a, b, c)

Z <- 2
block()
cat("Z:", Z, "a:", a, "b:", b, "c:", c, "\n")
## Z: 2 a: 1 b: 2 c: 3
```

**2) attach** Generally it is better to avoid attaching environments to the search path since it can result in some unexpected behavior but it does provide another possible solution.  Define the `block2` function to return `environment()` and then attach the result of running the function.  Note that this does not put `a`, `b` and `c` into the global environment but rather attaches them in a separate environment, `block2()`, which is placed on the search path.  One can list the contents of that environment using `ls("block2()")` and remove that environment using `detach("block2()")` . No packages are used.

```
block2 <- function() {
  a <- 1
  b <- 2
  c <- 3
  environment()
}

Z <- 1
attach(block2())

search()   # note new 2nd element on search path
##  [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "block2()"          "package:stats"    
##  [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
##  [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
## [10] "package:base"  

ls("block2()")
## [1] "a" "b" "c"

cat("Z:", Z, "a:", a, "b:", b, "c:", c, "\n")
## Z: 1 a: 1 b: 2 c: 3 
detach("block2()")

Z <- 2
attach(block2())
cat("Z:", Z, "a:", a, "b:", b, "c:", c, "\n")
## Z: 2 a: 1 b: 2 c: 3
```

**3) quote/eval**  Put the statements of the block into a `quote({...})` and then `eval` it whenever they are to be run.  No packages are used.

```
block3 <- quote({
  a <- 1
  b <- 2
  c <- 3
})

Z <- 1
eval(block3)
cat("Z:", Z, "a:", a, "b:", b, "c:", c, "\n")
## Z: 1 a: 1 b: 2 c: 3 
rm(a, b, c)

Z <- 2
eval(block3)
cat("Z:", Z, "a:", a, "b:", b, "c:", c, "\n")
## Z: 2 a: 1 b: 2 c: 3
```